# How to use PHP json_encode to format array data with []

Tags: php, json

**Goal:**
Use json_encode to format array data into a specified format

This is the needed format for the data after running through PHP json_encode:

**NEEDED FORMAT**

```
{
    "top_level_data": [
     {
        "extension": {},
        "sub_level_data1": 0
     }
    ]
}
```

When I use this PHP:

```
$data = array('top_level_data' => array('extension' => array(),
                                'sub_level_data1' => 0
                                )
            )
$data = json_encode($data);
```

I get this incorrect Output:

```
{
    "top_level_data":{
        "extension":[],
        "sub_level_data1": 0
        }
}
```

**Question:** 
How can I modify my php to include the {} and the [] in the correct places as the Needed Format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how you're generating `$data`; if it's by the assignment you show then you can just add an extra layer of `array` at `top_level_data`, and cast the `extension` value to an object:

```
$data = array('top_level_data' => array(
                                    array('extension' => (object)array(),
                                          'sub_level_data1' => 0
                                          )
                                        )
            );
```

If however you get the `$data` from another source, you can modify it like this:

```
$data['top_level_data']['extension'] = (object)$data['top_level_data']['extension'];
$data['top_level_data'] = array($data['top_level_data']);
```

Both methods yield this JSON:

```
{
    "top_level_data": [
        {
            "extension": {},
            "sub_level_data1": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/PJ71s)

Answer (score 1):

[json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) will encode sequence array with `[]`. The sequence array should has index from `0` to `n`. For other array, associative array and object will encoded with `{}`. Use the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` parameter of `json_encode` all the array will be encoded with `{}`.

Example:

```
echo json_encode(range(1,3));                     // [1,2,3]
echo json_encode(array(2=>2));                    // {"2":2}
echo json_encode(range(1,3),JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);   // {"0":1,"1":2,"2":3}
echo json_encode((object)range(1,3));             // {"0":1,"1":2,"2":3}
```